# Quasar change word 'of' in table pagination label

Tags: quasar

Is it possible to change the word **of** in table pagination-label?

For example: change `1-10 of 100` for `1-10 de 100`

The function to change the label only provides (firstRowIndex, endRowIndex, totalRowsNumber).

Thanks.

**Edited | for i18n**

For example

```
export const ptPT = {
   general: {
     of: 'de',
   }
}
```

.vue file:

How to get pagination **of** word  to translate?

```
<p> {{$t("general.of")}} </p>
```

Comment: you are using i18n ?

Comment: Thanks Patel.I edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is that you can set the language in quasar and it will change it.

```
Quasar.lang.set(Quasar.lang.es)
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/LYpKNRB

Comment: Thanks Patel Pratil. It works great. I set quasar language pack on quasar.conf.js file: framework: {lang: 'pack_name', ... } https://quasar.dev/options/quasar-language-packs